# Validating Quarter months

Tags: c#

i want to validate the quarter months. I want to return `true` only if the first input is the first month in a quarter (e.g. January or April) and the second input is the last month in a quarter (e.g. March or December).

scenario 1

```
input one: January / index 1
input two: February / index 2

result = invalid
```

scenario 2

```
input one: January / index 1
input two: July / index 7

result = invalid
```

scenario 3

```
input one: January / index 1
input two: March / index 3

result = valid
```

scenario 4

```
input one: January / index 1
input two: June / index 6

result = valid
```

Comment: You say you want to "get quarter months", but in your examples it seems that you're simply validating a given month based on whether it's a quarter month? What exactly do you want, and what have you attempted so far to achieve it?

Comment: Please define what a quarter month is

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `index 1`? Do you have an array of months? And if so, what is at `index 0`?

Comment: why index one because the month of january is 1. month of feb is 2 so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said you need to provide a lot more information, but based on your example i imagine you need to write a method that accepts the index of the 2 inputs as such:

```
bool IsValidQuater(inputOneIndex, inputTwoIndex)
{
    if (inputOneIndex%3 == 1 && inputTwoIndex%3 == 0)
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }    
}
```